# Let's Encrypt with uWSGI

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, uwsgi, lets-encrypt

I'm attempting to follow [these instructions here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install an SSL cert for my domain. However, these instructions seem to assume that nginx is the only server. I'm using nginx with uwsgi. I'm new to both. I don't believe uwsgi has a 'webroot'(?).

My django app is served from `/home/me/myapp`. I've created the `.well-known` directory there, like so: `/home/me/myapp/.well-known`.

Using this command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/home/me/myapp -d myappdomain.com -d www.myappdomain.com
```

I get this error:

```
   Domain: www.myappdomain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.myappdomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/HOjaeQfDlYQzAYfwGLltammjg6kMnwChV-Bc9BL2bSA:
```

**How can I properly server the `.well-known` directory if I have uWSGI behind NGINX?**

Answer (score 3):

NGINX can be configured for serve `.well-known`, with this way no need to care serve with uWSGI or another proxy server.

This configuration will help. It's listens 80 port and serve `.well-known` files from location root which is same with certbot's webroot plugin. Other requests will be redirected to HTTPS of domain like need to be.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myappdomain.com www.myappdomain.com;

    location /.well-known/ {
        root /home/me/myapp;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this was how I solved.

```
location /.well-known {
    alias /home/user/webapp/.well-known;
}
```

In my server `.well-known` is located at `/var/www/html/.well-known`
So, in my `nginx` config file

```
location /.well-known {
    alias /var/www/html/.well-known;
}
```

Verify location of `.well-known` by `sudo find / -type d -name '.well-known'`